# Keep an up to date directory listing via filesystem watching

Tags: powershell

I'm using [heatseeker and PSReadline](https://github.com/rschmitt/heatseeker#powershell) to enable fuzzy completion of items in a directory heirachy.

However there are over 200k items in this directory, and `Get-ChildItem` responds in over 12 seconds.

Other solutions can get this down to about 8 seconds. ( robocopy, ripgrep, cmd.exe ,[System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles). However these all depend on rebuilding the directory listing. What I would like to do is maintain a cache.

Instead of

```
Get-ChildItem -Name -Attributes !D -Recurse | hs
```

I would like to do

```
[IO.File]::ReadAllText($(Resolve-Path listing-cache.txt)) | hs
```

and **something** in the background would keep "listing-cache.txt" up to date so **hs** would activate near instantaneously.

How could I write a powershell function to maintain a cache of the recursive directory listing?

Comment: If you can be sure you won't hit an 'Access Denied' on the files you are enumerating, this might be fast enough `$path = 'Fill_in_path_here'; [System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles($path, '*', 'AllDirectories')` ?

Comment: I mentioned that I tried all the alternatives. They are still in the order of 10seconds or so. The cached index file is instantaneous to the user.

Comment: My current workflow is to trigger the cache rebuild manually using a powershell readline trigger. https://gist.github.com/bradphelan/f3141cd1b2605ddb29ca50c61bd7e722

Comment: Nope, you edited the question and added the `[System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles` in only after I commented about it..

Comment: Yes you are correct. But the solutions I had already mentioned ( robocopy, ripgrep, cmd.exe ) do the same as **[System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles** which is iterate of the filesystem index. That takes time. Pick any programming language over library and you can iterate the filesystem and get a similar bad result. But thankyou anyway for attempting to assist.